# Text input in message dialog? ContentDialog?

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am wondering what is the best way to allow a user to input text into a MessageDialog in a Windows 10 universal app.(Forgot password system). From the research I've done this doesn't seem possible with a MessageDialog but can be accomplished with a ContentDialog. So far I've found [this](http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-10-xaml-tips-messagedialog-and-contentdialog) site which explains roughly how to use the ContentDialog, but not with text input, and [and this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) which does show how to use a textbox with a ContentDialog but the method shown seems quite complex to me.

So, does anyone know of any more simplistic way of doing this or is the MSDN way the simplest its going to get?

Thanks for any help

Nathan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, here's the strict minimum to achieve what you're looking for :

[image]

**Page :**

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog1 = new ContentDialog1();
            var result = await dialog1.ShowAsync();
            if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            {
                var text = dialog1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dialog (code) :**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof (string), typeof (ContentDialog1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public ContentDialog1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }

        private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Dialog (XAML) :**

```
<ContentDialog x:Class="App1.ContentDialog1"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
               xmlns:local="using:App1"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               x:Name="ContentDialog"
               Title="TITLE"
               PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
               PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
               SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
               SecondaryButtonText="Button2"
               mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ContentDialog, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

Answer (score 19):

I use such function to request text from user:

```
private async Task<string> InputTextDialogAsync(string title)
{
    TextBox inputTextBox = new TextBox();
    inputTextBox.AcceptsReturn = false;
    inputTextBox.Height = 32;
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
    dialog.Content = inputTextBox;
    dialog.Title = title;
    dialog.IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = true;
    dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Ok";
    dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel";
    if (await dialog.ShowAsync() == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        return inputTextBox.Text;
    else
        return "";
}
```

and its usage:

```
string text = await InputTextDialogAsync("Title");
```

Comment: hey @Kibernetik, this is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Height=32, use this:

```
public static async Task<string> ShowAddDialogAsync(string title)
    {
        var inputTextBox = new TextBox { AcceptsReturn = false };
        (inputTextBox as FrameworkElement).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        var dialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Content = inputTextBox,
            Title = title,
            IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = true,
            PrimaryButtonText = "Ok",
            SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel"
        };
        if (await dialog.ShowAsync() == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
            return inputTextBox.Text;
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Comment: Cast to `as FrameworkElement` is not needed. But otherwise +1