# Why call to ContentDialog.ShowAsync() hangs

Tags: c#, uwp

Why following code (thanks to [Aybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34538881/1232087)) hangs at line `var result = await dialog1.ShowAsync();` I was expecting it to get a simple user input and continue after user clicks OK. But the dialog UI does not even completely shows up. It just hangs with all white background. I just see on top of main window there is a small dialog window with white background and it just hangs there.

I've seen solutions to such issues such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456246/1232087). But as this solution suggests I'm using `async` on Button_Click event. The difference between the referenced solution and mine is that I'm using `UWP` and they are probably not. So, what I may be missing and how we can resolve the issue?

```
private async void myButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var dialog1 = new ContentDialog1();
  var result = await dialog1.ShowAsync(); //hangs here

  if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
  {
     var text = dialog1.Text;
  }
  ....
  ....
}
```

**Custom Dialog class**:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof (string), typeof (ContentDialog1), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public ContentDialog1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }

        private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm using latest versions of both `VS2017` and `Windows 10 Professional` Laptop. No tapping (touch device) or smart phone or tablet is involved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770422/11683?

Comment: Your code did work for me. The contentDialog worked well on my side. I cannot reproduce your issue.  What's your OS build version and project's target version?

Answer (score 0):

In doing exactly what you do, I'm able to successfully show the dialog.

There is either something we're not seeing in the code provided, or something because it works just fine.